# Node/Npm/Npx command in CMD open up new cmd window with REPL

Tags: node.js

I have install node 13.8.0 in windows 7. But when i run a js file with node app.js the terminal of VS code or cmd open REPL in a new cmd . NPM and NPX command do the same.
I am stuck please help me. Thank You

Comment: please post your package.json and what your exact command (ie `npm run start`)

Comment: i cant even create a project. I cannot install a package. even "npm init" command open a new terminal.

Comment: I ended up here after reinstalling and testing npm/npx/node commands on windows terminal on a new tab. Those commands kept opening a new cmd.exe instead of running them in my current session. After eventually closing the Terminal app and reopening it, it behaved as expected.